# How to stop outer-class execution until AlertDialog get user's response?

Tags: android, inner-classes, android-alertdialog

In my Android application when an user touch an overlayItem on the map for more than 1.5 seconds an AlertDialog appear.  I need user's answer (*alertDialogResult*) to either keep the overlayItem or remove it from the map.  However, after the AlertDialog inner-class get called, the outer-class continue it execution and at that point I do not have user's answer.

Any suggestions? Any alternative to AlertDialog?

```
    final Boolean alertDialogResult = false;

        if ( ( pressEndTime - pressStartTime ) > 1500 )  {  

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( mapView.getContext() );
            alertDialog.setTitle( "Warning!" );
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete the selected overlayItem?");
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        alertDialogResult = true;


                    }   
                });

                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

            alertDialog.show();

            longPress = true;

            if ( alertDialogResult  == true ) {
                AndroidMainActivity.sendDeleteOverlayRequest(mapView, overlayItemId);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need alertDialogResult flag, you can move

```
  AndroidMainActivity.sendDeleteOverlayRequest(mapView, overlayItemId);
```

to onClick of positiveButton

**Edit**: Your AlertDialog will not wait for user Interatction after it has been Initialized. That is why there is callback for Onclick.

Comment: IDE is asking me to both change mapView and OverlayItemId to final, would that have any unintended effect?

Comment: nope.. If you are not changing those variables then it should not matter

Comment: Well, everytime OnTouch get executed, overlayItemId changes... it is that what you refer?

Comment: then declare a function in your main activity with sendDeleteOverlayRequest and then call that function from onclick

Comment: Ok, I just notice that overlayItemId is assigned once and destructed everytime OnTouch() finish.  In short, it does not have any unintented effect while assuring the inner-class that the objects it is receving will last at least until OnTouch() finish. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put 
 *`AndroidMainActivity.sendDeleteOverlayRequest(mapView, overlayItemId);`* 
in the onClick of the positiveButton. 
This way only you can achieve what you are asking, ie. perform the action after the user input.